# how to connect registration form in the database in ms access vb.net

Tags: database, vb.net, ms-access, datagridview, registration

how to connect registration form into ms access database using vb.net and how to show it to datagridview and to users profile

there is no error its just didn't show in the database, i tried different codes and it is nothing happened
i try this one

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb

Imports System.IO



Public Class RegisterFrom

    Dim conn As New OleDbConnection



    Private Sub RegisterFrom_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        conn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=D:\Visual Studio\Database17.accdb"

    End Sub



    Private Sub btnRegister_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnRegister.Click

        Try

            conn.Open()



            Dim adapter As New OleDbDataAdapter()

            Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM enrollment", conn)

            adapter.InsertCommand = New OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO enrollment (Firstname, Middlename, Lastname, Birthday, Age, Gender, Address, Contactnumber, Email, Course, Year, Username, Passw, Guardianname, Number, Occupation) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", conn)



            adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Firstname", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = txtFname.Text

            adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Middlename", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = txtMname.Text

            adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Lastname", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = txtLname.Text

            adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Birthday", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = txtBday.Text

            adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Age", OleDbType.Integer).Value = Convert.ToInt32(txtAge.Text)

            adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Gender", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = cmbGender.SelectedItem.ToString()

            adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = txtAddress.Text

            adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Contactnumber", OleDbType.Integer).Value = Convert.ToInt32(txtContact.Text)

            adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = txtEmail.Text

            adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Course", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = cmbCourse.SelectedItem.ToString()

            adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Year", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = cmbYear.SelectedItem.ToString()

            adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = txtuname.Text

            adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = txtPassw.Text

            adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Guardian", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = txtGuardian.Text

            adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Number", OleDbType.Integer).Value = Convert.ToInt32(txtGuardianContact.Text)

            adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Occupation", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = txtOccu.Text



            Dim ds As New DataSet()

            adapter.Fill(ds, "enrollment")



            Dim newRow As DataRow = ds.Tables("enrollment").NewRow()

            newRow("Firstname") = txtFname.Text

            newRow("Middlename") = txtMname.Text

            newRow("Lastname") = txtLname.Text

            newRow("Birthday") = txtBday.Text

            newRow("Age") = Convert.ToInt32(txtAge.Text)

            newRow("Gender") = cmbGender.SelectedItem.ToString()

            newRow("Address") = txtAddress.Text

            newRow("Contactnumber") = Convert.ToInt32(txtContact.Text)

            newRow("Email") = txtEmail.Text

            newRow("Course") = cmbCourse.SelectedItem.ToString()

            newRow("Year") = cmbYear.SelectedItem.ToString()

            newRow("Username") = txtuname.Text

            newRow("Passw") = txtPassw.Text

            newRow("Guardianname") = txtGuardian.Text

            newRow("Number") = Convert.ToInt32(txtGuardianContact.Text)

            newRow("Occupation") = txtOccu.Text



            ds.Tables("enrollment").Rows.Add(newRow)

            adapter.Update(ds, "enrollment")



            MsgBox("Created Successfully!!!")



            ' Clearing the text of various controls

            ClearTextBoxes()

        Catch ex As Exception

            MsgBox("Error: " & ex.Message)

        Finally

            conn.Close()

        End Try

    End Sub



    Private Sub ClearTextBoxes()

        txtFname.Text = ""

        txtMname.Text = ""

        txtLname.Text = ""

        txtBday.Text = ""

        txtAge.Text = ""

        cmbGender.Text = ""

        txtAddress.Text = ""

        txtEmail.Text = ""

        txtContact.Text = ""

        cmbCourse.Text = ""

        cmbYear.Text = ""

        txtuname.Text = ""

        txtPassw.Text = ""

        txtGuardian.Text = ""

        txtGuardianContact.Text = ""

        txtOccu.Text = ""

    End Sub



    Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click

        Me.Hide()

        LoginForm.Show()

    End Sub



    Private Sub Button4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click

        If Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal Then

            Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized
```

Comment: Not sure why you're using a data adapter and `DataTable` in the first place. If you just want to insert a single record then create a command and call `ExecuteNonQuery`. For an `INSERT` that will either return 1 for success or throw an exception.

Comment: What's the point of retrieving every record in the database when you don't use them for anything? Not only that, you create a command containing a `SELECT` statement but you don't appear to be associating it with the data adapter. That would mean that calling `Fill` would throw an exception.

Comment: If you are debugging the program in visual studio, the updated database is in `bin\debug` folder.

Comment: @ShahramAlemzadeh, the connection string contains an absolute path outside the project for the database. Probably not idea but it does mean that there's no separate source database and working copy under the project.